# FedEx shipping calculation disappearing when ordering more than four tires

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, fedex

We're experiencing an odd issue with our Magento store: the calculated shipping price disappears when ordering more than four tires for some reason. This is such an odd issue, I'm not even sure where to start.

Here's how to replicate:

1. Go to http://tagmotorsports.com/pirelli-trofeo-r-991-gt3-458-speciale-488 and add two of each tire to the cart.
2. Estimate the shipping and tax by entering in a country, state and zip code.
3. It will return a shipping quote for four tires just fine.
4. Change the quantity of tires to anything beyond four and update the cart.
5. The FedEx shipping quote disappears.

I think it may have something to do with input settings, but I'm not even sure where to start at this point. Looking through the FedEx shipping method settings didn't reveal anything immediately that might be contributing to this issue.

Any help will be super appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My credentials correct, i have two store in single magento, store 1 display Fedex shipping cost, but store 2 not displaying shipping cost, how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's happening but I'd suggest a place to start the hunt.

1. In System>Configuration>Sales>ShippingMethods>Fedex, turn Debug Mode on.
2. Then in the /var/log look for the file shipping_fedex.log and delete or rename it
3. In Magento front-end, select 5 tires and add to cart.  Get freight quote.
4. View new log file and look for errors.

The log file fills up pretty quickly so it's good to clear it out before you start.  Once you have identified the error then you at least know where to start.